# Store value of JSON key in Bash variable

Tags: json, linux, bash

I have a JSON where I am storing it in a variable in my Bash script like this:

`RAW_JSON="{"secretKey": "ADFGHJKGBNJK"}"`

I wanted to store the value of secretKey in another variable called **secretValue**. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use [tag:jq].

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve double quotation (`"`) marks around the key and value, the syntax is:

```
$ RAW_JSON='{"secretKey": "ADFGHJKGBNJK"}'
$ echo "$RAW_JSON"
{"secretKey": "ADFGHJKGBNJK"}
```

Then `jq` can be used to return the value:

```
$ secretValue=$(echo "$RAW_JSON" | jq -r .secretKey)
$ echo "$secretValue"
ADFGHJKGBNJK
```

The `-r` parameter removes the quotes from the result.

Comment: Nice answer, but please make sure to surround variables with double quotes.

Comment: @mkayaalp, can you please update according to the above suggestion ?

Comment: @DeependraDangal I already have. See the edit.